# Kendo canvas chart title/legend overflow hidden

Tags: kendo-ui, html5-canvas, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

Kendo chart **title/legend** truncate/overflow hidden. **Chart is rendered as canvas**

Based on the resolution, chart **title/legend** get overlapping/hide. I have attached 
[JsFiddle Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@prasad/iDaMU)

I tried to use this option. **word-wrap: break-word** but it is rendering in the canvas. is there any other solution from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this issue has been resolved, with this piece of code

```
function OnChartRender(e) {
    var chart = e.sender;
    var titleText = chart.options.title.text;
    var width = chart._plotArea.categoryAxis.box.width();

    var wordsPerLine = Math.round(width / 100) * 2;
    //var wordsPerLine = Math.round((width / 100) * 1.75);

    var arr = titleText.split(" ");
    var newTitle = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if ((i + 1) % wordsPerLine == 0) {
            newTitle += arr[i].trim() + "\n";
        } else {
            newTitle += arr[i].trim() + " ";
        }
    }
    // console.log("Words : ", wordsPerLine, " Width:", width, (width / 100));
    chart.options.title.text = newTitle;
    chart._events.render = null;
    chart.refresh();
}
```

**Event has been fired during the chart rendering.**

Based on the resolution, the title has been spitted in new lines..

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a padding and other formatting to the legend to push it.

```
 legend: {
     position: "top",
     padding: {
         bottom:30
     }, 
 }
```

Comment: This will not work dr.... have you checked this snippet demo "https://dojo.telerik.com/@prasad/iDaMU".. pls have a lookup into this... let share your comments, how can overcome from this prb...

Comment: It sounded like from your question that long series titles were running over onto the chart. I suggested you give them more space to grow. By the way your snippet demo looked fine, I could not see a problem.